# Android: findViewById returns null

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a dynamicly created layout for my Activity (don't ask me why, it is not my project, but I was asked to edit it a little). And I'm trying to add another layout into it, sort of a status bar. I have a XML layout for the second layout im adding and this is what the code looks like:

```
AbsoluteLayout basicLayout = new AbsoluteLayout(this);
basicLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

setContentView(basicLayout);

LinearLayout logo_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_logo);
Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_back);
Button options = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_menu);
```

But findViewById returns null, which causes NullPointerExceptions whenever im trying to do something with the two buttons that are inside the LinearLayout. I tried to clean the project but it didn't help. Thanks for any advice on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `setContentView()` to `basicLayout`

so your `layout` is never initialized and your `buttons` and `layouts` are `null`

try `setContentView(R.layout.XML_LAYOUT_CONTAINING_YOUR_BUTTON);`

**EDIT**
   use layout Inflater

```
    setContentView(basicLayout);

    //create a view to inflate the layout from the xml
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.XML_LAYOUT, basicLayout,false); 

    //add the view to the basic layout
    basicLayout.addView(view);

    LinearLayout logo_layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_logo);
    Button back = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_back);
    Button options = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_menu);
```

Comment: But wont that backfire when Im adding views to the basicLayout later on? Like basicLayout.addView(some view)?

Answer (score 0):

If the buttons are located in the logo_layout you need to search within that specific layout.

```
Button back = (Button) logo_layout.findViewById(R.id.button_back);
```

Comment: I tried that, but than I get a NullPointerException because the logo_layout is also null